# How to get % Memory usage of a process using Performnace Counter in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory

I want to get the % of memory used by a process.
Right now, I'm able to get only the available memory by using:

```
PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available KBytes");
```

Is there a way to get the desired result, may be using some calculation? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "% of memory used"?

Comment: Like how much % of memory has been used by a particular process, and also could you please clarify on the difference between "Available MBytes" and "Working Set". I have noticed, that the output is TaskMgr is shown as Memory (Private Working Set).?

Comment: It is a meaningless number on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows.  The amount of memory available is a highly dynamic number, set by the size of the paging file.  Which Windows will grow and shrink based on demand.  The amount of physical RAM used by a process, the working set, is similarly unhelpful as Windows maps pages out on demand when other processes need RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing this on windows performance monitor, to keep in track of memory and CPU usages.

This link shows you how you do it

[application pool memory usage monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790684/application-pool-memory-usage-monitor)

Answer (score -1):

For current (given) process you can get the memory it allocated from  [Process.WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx)  property. Having total memory already, you do

```
var percent = ((totalMemory - givenProcMemory)/totalMemory) * 100 ;
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Tigran, I'll go for it :) But, would you please clarify difference between "Available MBytes" and "Working Set". I mean, which one shall I use for performance monitoring of all processes in the Server?

Comment: I think to make *precise* calculations you have to read about a server and process you're going to investigate on (ASP.NET web server?). But "basicaly" it has to return amount of memory available on machine for all processes (occupied or not)