# Application Pool memory usage History

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Recently we experienced crashing on application (ASP.Net) with below issue since issue is resolved but a question arises in my mind; can we capture history of memory used by application? I want to add a job which will capture application memory usage after each half an hour.

> Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (373817344 bytes)
>   is less than 5% of total memory. As a result, the service will not be
>   available for incoming requests. To resolve this, either reduce the
>   load on the machine or adjust the value of
>   minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the
>   serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

**Edit**: Question arise from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790684/application-pool-memory-usage-monitor)

Comment: Windows has a performance monitor system. Add the counters that you are interested in, you can get the trace you want. Meanwhile, System Center Operation Manager can do more for you.

Comment: can we query those counters from SQL?

Comment: You can use extended events to capture/record history, and query the resultset if needed.

Comment: @Greg, do you have reference to those queries?